org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized field "error" not marked as ignorable
I have this DTO which I'm using for request and response DTO between two microservices:
      HttpEntity<ProfileResource> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request);
      ResponseEntity<ProfileResource> response = null;
      try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, ProfileResource.class,
                Collections.emptyMap());
      } catch (Exception ex) {.....}

DTO:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import java.util.List;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NON_PRIVATE)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
public class ProfileResource {

  private String firstName;
  private Error error;
  .......
}

............

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Error implements ErrorCode {

  private String code;
}

Into receiving microservices I get error:
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 : "{"error":{"code":"5023","message":"You submitted a request that is not parseable.: field 'error' not recognized",

Do you know how I can fix this issue? Maybe the solution is to ignore the value error?
Solution:
I managed to fix the issue by adding:
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) 
private Error error;


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false) is giving this error.
You are tightly coupling the API response with what you are expecting
Change it to
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ProfileResource {

Also make sure Error class has this
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

public class Error


Is it possible to configure only for value error to allow to be null? For other values I need to have the tightly couple the API response.

Yes you can do that as well. @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false) and you need custom deserializer for Error

Updated a new answer for the requirement lol

I tested it but it's not working. Please see the updated post to guide you what is the original code.

Can you guide me is it possible to configure the sender microservice to ignore sending Error of the value in null?

Have tried my second answer

Unfortunately no, in my case I need to fix this without making a lot of changes. Other ideas?

p.s I tried with setting @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) and with @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT) but I can see into the request "error": null, Maybe because of a but these settings are ignored? I use the latest Spring Cloud version.

It doesnt need much changes all you got to do is add custom ErrorDeserializer class
public class ErrorDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {
@Override
public Error deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) parser.getCodec();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); // Disable for Error only
return mapper.readValue(parser, Error.class);
}
}

ok, I will try it. But do you know why the configuration setting @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) and with @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT) for the sending microservice is not working?

I managed to fix the issue by adding @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) private Error error;

Option2: Based on your comments above you can follow this as well
To throw an error for unknown fields in your main class but allow unknown fields in the Error class, use @JsonIgnoreProperties and a custom deserializer:

Set @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false) on your main class to enforce strict deserialization:
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
public class ProfileResource {
    // Define known fields here
}


Add a custom deserializer to Error to allow unknown fields specifically for this class:
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonDeserialize(using = ErrorDeserializer.class)
public class Error {
    // Define error fields here
}


Custom ErrorDeserializer:
public class ErrorDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Error> {
    @Override
    public Error deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) parser.getCodec();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); // Disable for Error only
        return mapper.readValue(parser, Error.class);
    }
}



This setup will throw errors for unknown fields in ProfileResource, but allow them in Error.
